# Preset on Premiere Pro paste keyframes on particular place instead of the end of clip (bag?)

Tags: animation, adobe, caption, adobe-premiere, preset

On Adobe Premiere Pro 2023 animation preset (which is anchored to out point) pastes keyframes on the particular place on the text clip/graphic (which is previosly upgraded from captions) and not on the end of clip.

On some clips this preset work just fine, but on these clips it's makes this strange bug.

Looks like the preset is ignoring the "Anchor to put point" setting. I can't figure out the reason (i tried google it but didn't find anything related)